# TypeError: type datetime.datetime doesn't define __round__ method

Tags: python, rounding, python-datetime

I'm working on an API with Python. When trying to parse the data that I got from my database, I got this error: `TypeError: type datetime.datetime doesn't define __round__ method`.

api.py:

```py
response = []
for i in range(len(histTuple)):
        currentTime = histTuple[i][2].replace(microsecond=0)
        currentTime = str(currentTime) + f" GMT{TIMEZONE}"
        response.append({"humidity": round(histTuple[1][i], 1), "celsius": round(histTuple[0][i]), "fahrenheit": round(histTuple[0][i] * 9/5 + 32), "timestamp": currentTime}) # error here
```

I'm not trying to round a `datetime.datetime`, and `currentTime` isn't even a string!

Comment: Check your index try [i][1] instead of [1][i] for humidity, [i][0] for celcius, and [i][0] for fahrenheit

Comment: This could be written more cleanly (and less prone to error) with a loop like `for hist in histTuple` so that you can access the values inside each tuple as `hist[0]`, `hist[1]` and `hist[2]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My query was in this format: `[(temperature,),(temperature,),(temperature,)]`

So, flipping the indexes, it worked.